# How to override LoginDisplay in Blazor Identity Server 4 in ASP.NET Core WebAssembly .NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-scaffolding

Maybe have some question related to override existing authentication/authorization in ASP.NET Core 3 . My question is in another specific context (not duplicated question).

I am using ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly on .NET 5 (version 5.0.102), Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.4 (lastest technology stack at the current time). I create project from template of Blazor WebAssembly template .NET 5 with individual account from Identity Server 4.

This is file `MainLayout.razor`

[image]

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div class="page">
    @*
        <div class="sidebar">
            <NavMenu />
        </div>*@

    <div class="main">
        <div class="px-4 auth">
            <!-- <div class="top-row px-4 auth" />-->
            <!-- Thêm menu vào đây -->

            <DxMenu></DxMenu>

            <div class="top-row">
                <LoginDisplay />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code{
    void GotoHome()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

When I integrated with other UI framework, CSS of Identity Server 4 is conflict, cause defect at UI. I need override/rewrite UI razor page(s) (`<LoginDisplay />`) of Identity Server 4, how to do it?